# Internet Explorer caching get-request

Tags: http, silverlight, sharepoint, request

Writing silverlight web part for SharePoint 2010. IE caching GET-requests and DataGrid doesn't refresh data. In local server all works fine, in Chrome all works fine. If cache in IE turned off, all works fine. The problem is only in IE. How can i solve it.
Work with HTTP goes through WebClient class.

Comment: I'm not familiar with WebClient, but I think the easiest solution is to just add a random URL parameter or setting [WebClient.CachePolicy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.cachepolicy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `NoCacheNoStore`.

Comment: WebClient.CachePolicy doesn't exist in Silverlight